# Sorting array of arrays of weekdays (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date, days

Having next array (e.g.):

```
[
 ['Tue', 'Fri'],
 ['Mon'],
 ['Mon', 'Thu', 'Sun'],
 ['Wed', 'Thu', 'Sun'],
 ['Tue', 'Wed']
]
```

I need to sort it to get next:

```
[
 ['Mon'],
 ['Mon', 'Thu', 'Sun'],
 ['Tue', 'Wed'],
 ['Tue', 'Fri'],
 ['Wed', 'Thu', 'Sun']
]
```

Does not mean how much days in array can be - if it's more that 1, others should be sorted respectively to their position index in week.

How such sorting function can be implemented? Thanks.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  I see a programming problem without an attempt at solving it.  SO is not a place that does your work for you

Comment: Are you able to change the structure of the dataset? Instead of just an array could you use some key value pairing? That way each day could have an index corresponding to it's position in the week.

Comment: Sorting of arrays in JavaScript is done with [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: @FNTNBWIH yes, I able to change the structure of dataset in any way, but I don't know which is better. Actually provided structure is already changed - in original I have just bitmask of days.

Comment: @vol7ron I'm stuck with implementing sorting function that will respect sorting rule which I've described.
I tried to solve it giving a weight to each day, but that does not work if we have, say, `Mon, Sut` and `Tue, Wed`. Say each day have it's weight equal to it's index. `Mon + Sut` gives 5 and `Tue + Wed` gives 3, meaning `Tue, Wed` should go before `Mon, Sut`, but it's wrong.

Comment: Replace `Mon` with `a`, `Tue` with `b`, ... `Sun` with `g`. Concatenate the characters and sort the strings.

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks, I fixed this

Answer (score 3):

This does not take every case into concern, but performs the following:

- uses a pre-described ordering object

  - using an ordering list makes it easier to switch sunday from first to last (or have some other custom/weighted ordering)
  - you are not limited to an *object* and could use an array (retrieving the index) or Date (converting the day), but I think an Object or Set might be more efficient
- uses recursion to evaluate the next element in the case that a tie exists

  - if there is no next element the order (`_a` or `_b`) defaults to `0`, since a lack of an element is higher priority
  - you could place a check in there to avoid the recursive call altogether

```js
let order = {
 'Mon':1,
 'Tue':2,
 'Wed':3,
 'Thu':4,
 'Fri':5,
 'Sat':6,
 'Sun':7
}

let arr = [
 ['Tue', 'Fri'],
 ['Mon'],
 ['Mon', 'Thu', 'Sun'],
 ['Wed', 'Thu', 'Sun'],
 ['Tue', 'Wed']
]


let sorted = arr.sort(sortElements)
console.log('sorted:',sorted)


function sortElements(a,b,ndx=0){
  let _a = order[ a[ndx] ] || 0
  let _b = order[ b[ndx] ] || 0
    
  if ( _a === _b && (a.length > ndx || b.length > ndx))
    return sortElements(a,b,ndx+1)
  else
    return _a - _b
}
```

Comment: ` [
    "Tue",
    "Fri"
  ],
  [
    "Tue",
    "Wed"
  ],`he does not follow the example he requested

Comment: I did not see you changed your answer, I'm sorry

Comment: @vol7ron the OP had typos in the code. He fixed it and your answer could be made much simpler.

Comment: it does not solve the nested days in an array for sorting the outer array.

Comment: @NinaScholz there you go -- hope that it's easy enough to follow w/o comments

Comment: Good job +1 ;) have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

If you can restructure the data, this might help.

```
 let days = [
  {day:'Mon',index:1},
  {day:'Sat',index:6},
  {day:'Sun',index:0},
  {day:'Wed',index:3},
  {day:'Tue',index:2},
  {day:'Thu',index:4},
  {day:'Fri',index:5},
];

days.sort((a,b) => {return a.index > b.index});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function compareArray , just to determine order of two arrays, say ['Tue', 'Wed'] and ['Tue', 'Fri']. and then used it in sort function

```js
var arr = [
 ['Tue', 'Fri'],
 ['Mon'],
 ['Mon', 'Thu', 'Sun'],
 ['Wed', 'Thu', 'Sun'],
 ['Tue', 'Wed']
]

var order = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']


var compareArray = (arr1, arr2) => {
  for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
     if(!arr2[i]) {return 1}
    if(order.indexOf(arr1[i]) < order.indexOf(arr2[i])) {
       return -1;
   } else if(order.indexOf(arr1[i]) > order.indexOf(arr2[i])){ 
      return 1;
  }
 }
  return 0;
}

arr.sort((a,b) => compareArray(a,b))

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object with sortable items, which could be stacked in a string.

```js
const
    days = { Mon: 'a', Tue: 'b', Wed: 'c', Thu: 'd', Fri: 'e', Sat: 'f', Sun: 'g' },
    getV = a => a.map(d => days[d]).join('');

var array = [['Tue', 'Fri'], ['Mon'], ['Mon', 'Thu', 'Sun'], ['Wed', 'Thu', 'Sun'], ['Tue', 'Wed']];

array.sort((a, b) => getV(a).localeCompare(getV(b)));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this

Answer (score 0):

If you write two functions to convert names to values and values to names, it is a one-liner.

```js
function dayvalue (day)
{
  switch (day) {
  case 'Mon': return 0;
  case 'Tue': return 1;
  case 'Wed': return 2;
  case 'Thu': return 3;
  case 'Fri': return 4;
  case 'Sat': return 5;
  case 'Sun': return 6;
  }
}

function dayname (value)
{
  switch (value) {
  case 0: return 'Mon';
  case 1: return 'Tue';
  case 2: return 'Wed';
  case 3: return 'Thu';
  case 4: return 'Fri';
  case 5: return 'Sat';
  case 6: return 'Sun';
  }
}

var days = [
  ['Tue', 'Fri'],
  ['Mon'],
  ['Mon', 'Thu', 'Sun'],
  ['Wed', 'Thu', 'Sun'],
  ['Tue', 'Wed']
];

console.log(days.map(names => names.map(dayvalue)).sort().map(values => values.map(dayname)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by converting each array in a string representaton and use [`String.prototype.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for sorting:

```js
const input = [['Tue', 'Fri'],['Mon'],['Mon', 'Thu', 'Sun'],['Wed', 'Thu', 'Sun'],['Tue', 'Wed']];

const days = {Mon:'a', Tue:'b', Wed:'c', Thu:'d', Fri:'e', Sat:'f', Sun:'g'};

const sorted = input.sort((a,b) => {
    const [aLoc, bLoc] = [a,b].map(e => e.map(d => days[d]).join(''));
    return aLoc.localeCompare(bLoc);
});

console.log(sorted);
```